# Do I lose reputation if I delete my own question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, reputation, deleted-questions

Do I lose reputation if I delete my own question which has been answered and gain some reputation over time on StackOverflow?

Comment: if the question has accepted (or not accepted) answer and/or has upvote or star then that question may be useful to other user/visitor. It is better not to delete useful or helpful question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

> - Deleting and undeleting posts may affect reputation as well, if these posts have votes. Actions taken on deleted posts cease to affect reputation within five minutes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)), unless the post meets the following criteria (in which case the reputation affects will be permanent) ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)):
>   - The post had a score of at least +3
>   - The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days